# Create table/column if not exists for DB2 - Not using a sp, just manual query

Tags: sql, create-table, db2-400

I tried using the SQL syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PWRNTCDT.customers_contacts(
    customer_id varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  contact_index INT NOT NULL,
  is_primary SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  f_name varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  l_name varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  job_title varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  phone varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  mobile varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

and I got an error indicating a syntax error on the "exists" part.
Couldn't find anything online.
Thanks!

Comment: Which code did you try, which error did you get?

Comment: @GMB I edited the question with more info. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is tagged by 2 different db2 platforms. They have different capabilities. What's your exact db2 platform and version?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a `CREATE TABLE` functionality in DB2 for IBM i.
There is `CREATE OR REPLACE` but not `CREATE IF NOT EXISTS`.
Refer to the [CREATE TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzhctabl.htm) statement description in the documentation.

But you may use [Dynamic compound statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/sqlp/rbafydyncompound.htm) for this.

```
-- Use some another statement terminator in your tool you run this statement from like "@" as below
-- Or don't use this statement terminator at all, if you run the statement from some external program
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS
  (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM QSYS2.SYSTABLES
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='PWRNTCDT' AND TABLE_NAME='CUSTOMER_CONTACTS'
  ) THEN

  CREATE TABLE PWRNTCDT.customers_contacts
  (
  customer_id varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  contact_index INT NOT NULL,
  is_primary SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  f_name varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  l_name varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  job_title varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  phone varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  mobile varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL
  );

  END IF;
END@
```